# Django Model Instance - Saving other attributes

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I'm trying to support user uploads in my Django Application. The application should allow a user to create his own repo of files and folders.

The below is my model instance

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Folders(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255,default = 'Main')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Case)

class Files(models.Model):
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folders)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_url)


def get_upload_url(instance,filename):
    print('Instance is :',instance)
    return '/'.join([instance.folder.project.name,instance.folder.name,filename])
```

I'm getting an error when i'm trying to upload docs to specific folders using django forms

```
def ProjectPageAlt(request,casenum,folder):
    proj = Project.objects.get(pk=casenum)
    folder = Folders.objects.get(name = folder,project=proj)
    files = Files.objects.filter(folder=folder) or None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileUploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form
            instance[folder] = folder
            # form.folder = folder
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponse('thanks')
    else:
        form = FileUploadForm()
    return render(request,'projectuploadalternative.html',{'form':form,'files':files})
```

I'm getting the below error because i'm trying to add the folder instance to the model before saving

```
'FileUploadForm' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there anyway around this? I need to ensure that the file gets uploaded to the appropriate folder

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around. But this sounds more like a hack to me.

```
def CasePageAlt(request,casenum,folder):
    case = Case.objects.get(pk=casenum)
    folder = Folders.objects.get(name = folder,case=case)
    files = Files.objects.filter(folder=folder) or None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileUploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['upload']
            instance = Files(folder=folder,file=file)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponse('thanks')
    else:
        form = FileUploadForm()
    return render(request,'caseuploadalternative.html',{'form':form,'files':files})
```

This works because the initial form that i had was a ModelForm. Now i made the form a normal one

Previous

```
# class FileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
#
#     class Meta:
#         model = Files
#         fields = ['file']
```

new

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.Form):

    upload = forms.FileField()
```